# plot dataframe in boxplots in chucks of values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, boxplot

I have a one-column Dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 1),
                      columns=['Time'])
df['EDGE'] = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'A', 'B','C','C', 'B','D','A','E','F','F','A','G','H','H','A'])
df
```

The real dataframe has several hundred thousands of lines and the list of unique 'EDGE' values is around 200

I want to plot the results in a boxplot manner as follows:

```
boxplot = df.boxplot(by='EDGE')
```

Now there are so many values that I have to print bit a bit, just say in the same plot first the 10 first letters.
On the other hand I want to print first the values with the greater mean time.

Expected result:
A colections of boxplots every boxplot including 10 EDGEs. The boxes appearing in descending order regarding the average 'TIME'.

How to proceed?

WHAT DID i TRIED?

I tried to make on sub_df with loc for every value, but then I would only get one box per boxplot
I tried to use groupby to gourp by "EDGE" at no avail because I dont know how to plot only the first n groups of the dataframe

NOTE: I pretend to use as less libraries as possible, i.e. if i can do it with pandas better than with matplotlib, and matplotlib better than using yet another library on top of matplotlib

Comment: yes / corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an intermediate frame `groups` with the assignment of the EDGEs to the plot number (column `Order`) and the EDGE positions within each plot (column `Pos`).

```
chunk_size = 3

groups = df.groupby('EDGE')
groups = (groups.ngroups - groups.Time.mean().rank(method='first').astype(int)).to_frame()
groups['Order'] = groups.Time // chunk_size
groups['Pos'] = groups.Time % chunk_size

for i in range(groups.Order.max() + 1):
    group = groups[groups.Order==i]
    df[df.EDGE.isin(group.index)].boxplot(by='EDGE', positions=group.Pos)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 1), columns=['Time'])
df['EDGE'] = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'A', 'B','C','C', 'B','D','A','E','F','F','A','G','H','H','A'])

# code from above ...

#verification:
print(df.groupby('EDGE').Time.mean().sort_values(ascending=False))
#EDGE
#G    1.494079
#B    1.367285
#E    0.761038
#A    0.442789
#F    0.282769
#D    0.144044
#H    0.053955
#C   -0.127288
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, then you can do it with reshaping the dataframe

```
# define the number of edges per plot
nb_edges_per_plot = 4 #to change to your needs

# group by edge
gr = df.groupby('EDGE')['Time']
# get the mean per group and sort them 
order_ = gr.mean().sort_values(ascending=False).index
print (order_) #order depends on the random value so probably not same for you
#Index(['D', 'H', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'G', 'F'], dtype='object', name='EDGE')

# reshape your dataframe to ake each EDGE a column and order the columns
df_ = df.set_index(['EDGE', gr.cumcount()])['Time'].unstack(0)[order_]
print (df_.iloc[:5, :5])
# EDGE         D         H         C         B         A
# 0     1.729417  0.270593 -0.140786 -0.540270  0.862832
# 1          NaN  0.647830  1.038952 -0.129361 -0.648432
# 2          NaN       NaN       NaN -1.235637 -0.430890
# 3          NaN       NaN       NaN  0.631744 -1.622461
# 4          NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.694052
```

Now you can just `boxplot` with `groupby`. For plotting each group of edges on subplots, do:

```
df_.groupby(np.arange(len(order_))//nb_edges_per_plot, axis=1).boxplot()
```

or if you want separated figures, then you can do

```
for _, dfg_ in df_.groupby(np.arange(len(order_))//nb_edges_per_plot, axis=1):
    dfg_.plot(kind='box')
```

or even in one line you can get separated figures, see the difference is instead of using `boxplot()` use `plot.box()`. Note that the loop version is more flexible if you want to change parameters in each plot

```
df_.groupby(np.arange(len(order_))//nb_edges_per_plot, axis=1).plot.box()
```